# textarea size increase via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

JavaScript:

```
function x() {
    var value = document.getElementById("test1").value.length;
    if (value <= 18) {
        value.rows = 1;
    } else if (value > 18 && value < 36) {
        value.rows = 2;
    } else if (value > 36 && value < 54) {
        value.rows = 3;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="textarea" id="test1" style="overflow:auto" rows="1" cols="18" onkeypress="javascript:x();">
```

3 questions:

1. How can I remove these `if-else` via for or while loop?
2. Max size of the field should be 18 but right now it doesnt work
   exact at 18 even though I made `cols="18"`.
3. Is "onkeypress" the best option? I use the event to delete the value inside a
   textbox either use delete or backspace which are not part of
   "keypress". So basically it doesn't dynamically decrease the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only to 1)

First you need to set the row to the test1 object not to the value:

```
document.getElementById("test1").rows = xxx;
```

Then you did skip the handling for the values of 36 and 54. This should be probably `<= 36` and `<= 54`.

Then this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("test1")

if (value == 0) textarea.rows = 1;
else if (value > 54) textarea.rows = 3;
else textarea.rows = Math.floor((value - 1) / 18) + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Textarea is the tag not an attribute value

```
<textarea id="test1" style="overflow:auto" rows="1" cols="18">Text goes here</textarea>
```

For the javascript you are assigning the length to the variable, not the element.
So kinda like

```
var a = document.getElementById("test1");

a.rows = (a.value.length / 18) + 1;
```

This is untested code.